# Raid 5 suddenly missing two hdd at the same time

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I made a raid 5 with 4 drives

```
/dev/sdh3
/dev/sdi3
/dev/sdj3
/dev/sdk3
```

Normally I started raid with this command

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md128 /dev/sdh3 /dev/sdi3 /dev/sdj3 /dev/sdk3
```

Suddenly something happen with two drives at the same time.

I can't find `/dev/sdk3`

```
$fdisk -l /dev/sdk
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdk: No such file or directory
```

also `/dev/sdj3` disappeared

However, I can examine and see `/dev/sdj` not `/dev/sdj3`

```
/dev/sdj:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a9bcec2a:5772e6a5:045f28ac:62ae0002
           Name : 0a438048:RaidSecond-0  (local to host 0a438048)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 08:59:59 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789616 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 23427527424 (22342.23 GiB 23989.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15618351616 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
    Data Offset : 263552 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=263272 sectors, after=9438000 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 05652fdf:8edc650e:9cea98d8:36aee81d

    Update Time : Sun Dec 27 14:52:58 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 600bad80 - correct
         Events : 48292

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

other than `/dev/sdj` there is raid partition `/dev/sd*3` same as before

```
$mdadm --examine /dev/sdh
/dev/sdh:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)


$mdadm --examine /dev/sdh3
/dev/sdh3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a9bcec2a:5772e6a5:045f28ac:62ae0002
           Name : 0a438048:RaidSecond-0  (local to host 0a438048)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 08:59:59 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15618352320 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
     Array Size : 23427527424 (22342.23 GiB 23989.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15618351616 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
    Data Offset : 263552 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=263272 sectors, after=704 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1d396d49:23a9dd4f:648792aa:3acd8cc3

    Update Time : Sun Dec 27 14:52:58 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 82cf0985 - correct
         Events : 48292

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

$mdadm --examine /dev/sdi
/dev/sdi:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)

$mdadm --examine /dev/sdi3
/dev/sdi3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a9bcec2a:5772e6a5:045f28ac:62ae0002
           Name : 0a438048:RaidSecond-0  (local to host 0a438048)
  Creation Time : Tue Sep 22 08:59:59 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 15618352320 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
     Array Size : 23427527424 (22342.23 GiB 23989.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15618351616 (7447.41 GiB 7996.60 GB)
    Data Offset : 263552 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=263272 sectors, after=704 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : de2cdd77:9d05827f:2e57e5ae:8c2f1d48

    Update Time : Sun Dec 27 14:52:58 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 264 sectors
       Checksum : 69c68bdd - correct
         Events : 48292

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

So I have two questions.

Why `/dev/sdk3` disappeared suddenly and how can I find it??

Why `/dev/sdj3` changed to `/dev/sdj`?
and Is it ok to recover raid with `mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdh3 /dev/sdi3 /dev/sdj` temporally?